# <f:setPropertyActionListener> is called on first record of <p:subTable> only

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Take a look at following code :

```
<p:accordionPanel id="accord" multiple="false" dynamic="true"
    value="#{makelineMB.billNotYetGeneratedOrders}" var="orderList">
    <p:tab title="#{makelineMB.getOrderTypeByList(orderList)}">
        <p:dataTable var="sglOrd" value="#{orderList}">
            <p:columnGroup type="header">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column headerText="Item" />
                    <p:column headerText="Qty" />
                    <p:column headerText="Price" />
                    <p:column headerText="Kitchen Status" />
                </p:row>
            </p:columnGroup>

            <p:subTable var="lineItem" value="#{sglOrd.orderLineItems}">

                <f:facet name="header">
                        #{sglOrd.orderNo} 
                        <p:spacer height="0" width="5" />
                        Total Amt: $#{sglOrd.total}
                        <p:spacer height="0" width="5" />                       
                    <p:commandButton id="cmdBtn_printBill" icon="ui-icon-print"
                        value="Collect Bill"
                        oncomplete="PF('printBill_dlg_widgetVar').show()"
                        update=":dailyorderform:printBill_dlg" style="float:right;">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener
                            target="#{makelineMB.orderToPrint}" value="#{sglOrd}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </f:facet>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{lineItem.menuItemName.toUpperCase()}" />
                </p:
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{lineItem.price}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{makelineMB.getOrderLineStatus(lineItem.status)}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:subTable>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

This code renders following UI :

[image: result of above code]

Each tab contains order category and displays the orders in that category. Each order header having the `<p:commandButton>` and associated `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`.

However, the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` get called on only first record of each tab other rendered orders collect bill `<p:commandButton>` does not fire `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`.  How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is the whole code piece wrapped by a form?

Comment: yes <h:form id="dailyorderform">

Comment: I will try to replicate the error. I need the Primefaces version you are using. Is this declaration correct: <p:dataTable var="sglOrd" value="#{orderList}">? It appears to me that you have a collection of bills and every bill has a collection of orders and every order has a collection of items. Is that right?

Comment: I am using primefaces 4.0. The declaration is correct that's why it's showing line item for each sglOrd object.

Comment: I have collection of Order                           <p:accordionPanel id="accord" multiple="false" dynamic="true"
    value="#{makelineMB.billNotYetGeneratedOrders}" var="orderList"> billNotYetGeneratedOrder returns me List<List<Order>>

Comment: Hi friends I solved my problem by making changes in UI

Comment: I use simple html <table> instead of dataTable and subtable.